# Is $f$ Riemann-Stieltjes integrable? If so, compute the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Determine if $f\in \mathcal{R}_{\alpha}[-1,1]$, and if so calculate $\int_{-1}^{1}f\,d\alpha$ using the definition of the RS integral (you may apply Theorem 6.6 if you wish)
>
> $f(x)=x$, $\alpha(x)=\begin{cases} 0 \ \ (x=-1)\\ 1 \ \ (-1<x\leq 0) \\ 3 \ \ (0<x<1) \\ 5 \ \ (x=1) \end{cases}$

Theorem 6.8 states that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f\in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$. So this $f$ must be $f\in \mathcal{R}_{\alpha}[-1,1]$, right? However, I cannot find a "nice" partition so that $U(P)-L(P)<\epsilon$.

Comment: The only time you pick up a contributions is when the function $\alpha$ jumps from one plateau to the next. On the same plateau you have $\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i+1})=0$. This leaves you with at most four terms for any partition that is fine enough. Pretty sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I naively think I should take some number arbitrarily close to $-1$, $0$, and $1$? For example, letting $P=${$-1,-0.999,0,0.001,0.999,1$}, I get $U(P)-L(P)=0.005$. So, letting $-0.999, 0.001,$ and $0.999$ arbitrarily close to $-1, 0,$ and $1$, respectively is a nice partition here?

Comment: You can also do an equidistant partition $x_j=2j/N-1$. Then for $N\geq 3$ you get that the error is bounded by $ (1+2+2)\cdot 2/N = 10/N$. More generally, if $\delta$ is the maximal distance in your partition the error is bounded by $5 \delta$.

Comment: Oh that looks easier to rigorously write down the proof. Thank you!

Comment: You can also integrate by parts, then you have easy partitions with $x\alpha - \int \alpha dx$

Answer (score 1):

Let $-1=x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_N < x_{N+1}=1$ be a partition $P$ of $[-1,1]$. We define
$$ \delta = \max_{i\in \{0, \dots, N \}} (x_{i+1}-x_i). $$

Assume that $\delta<1$.
Then there exists $\beta$ such that $x_{\beta}\leq 0 < x_{\beta+1}<1$ and we have
$$ \alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i) =0 $$
unless $i\in \{0, \beta, N\}$. Let $\widetilde{x}_i$ such that $x_i \leq \widetilde{x}_i \leq x_{i+1}$. Hence, we get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=0}^N f(\widetilde{x}_i) (\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i)) \\
&= f(\widetilde{x}_0)(\alpha(x_1)-\alpha(-1)) + f(\widetilde{x}_\beta) (\alpha(x_{\beta +1}-\alpha(x_\beta)) + f(\widetilde{x}_N) (\alpha(1)-\alpha(x_N)) \\
&= f(\widetilde{x}_0) + 2f(\widetilde{x}_\beta) + 2f(\widetilde{x}_N).
\end{align*}
We have $\vert \widetilde{x}_0-(-1)\vert \leq \delta$, $\vert \widetilde{x}_\beta \vert \leq \delta$ and $\vert \widetilde{x}_N - 1\vert \leq \delta$. Thus, for $\delta \rightarrow 0^+$ and $f$ continuous we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^N f(x_i) (\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i)) \rightarrow f(-1)+2f(0)+2f(1).$$
This tells us that $f\in \mathcal{R}_\alpha[-1,1]$ and
$$ \int_{-1}^1 fd\alpha = f(-1)+2f(0)+2f(1). $$